# Empty sessions in Django

Tags: python, django, session

I'm unable to write session keys and values to the session file using Django 1.5, Python 2.7 (64 bits), and Windows OS. I set the `SESSION_ENGINE` variable as `django.contrib.sessions.backends.file`, and the `SESSION_FILE_PATH` as `C://Users//Doboro//My Documents//Aptana Studio 3 Workspace//test//src`

The session file is created with the name "`sessionid3i52btehkwssb6xzd2p7dmyovkq1cts4`", **but it's EMPTY.**

My view has the following code:

```
def index(request):
    last_id = User.objects.order_by('-pk')[0].id
    request.session['last_id'] = last_id
    context.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'templates/index.html', context)
```

Any thoughts? **I've also added the `request.session.modified=True` and `request.session.save()` but with the same results...**

Comment: have you tried django.contrib.sessions.backends.db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and there is a [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9084) opened.